# Nested forms issue - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have some rails  nested forms

```
    = form_for @model do |f|
    ...
      = f.fields_for :user_partnership do |builder|
        - user_partners.each do |index|
          = builder.hidden_field :user_partner_id
          = content_tag(:li,index.name)
```

In my `model` I have set `has_many :user_partner, through: :users_partnership`.

So now I have two problems : the first, I have no input inside the `fields_for` process. So, following some `SO` posts, I had to add this

```
@model = model.new
@user_partners = User_Partner.all
@user_partners.count.times{@model.users_partnership.build}
```

but this really seam awkward. The secound question is how I get the enumerator of the `fields_for` block so I can set correctly `index.name` ?

Edit, here's my models

```
class model
  has_many :user_partners, through: :users_partnerships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users_partnerships
end

class User_Partner
  has_many :models, through: :users_partnerships
end

class Users_Partnership
  belongs_to :model
  belongs_to :user_partner
end
```

Comment: It feels like there are so many missing connections, can you post your models in question and explain a little more what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure your `model` class is infact all lower-case, and the other two classes have underscore in them?  Also, don't they inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`?  More importantly what I want another clarification is what is `users` in your view, where does it come from?

Comment: @vinodadhikary sorry i have edited my post, it is in fact `user_partners` and not `users`. Btw, I tried ` = builder.options[:child_index]` to see if the index was showing, but nothong was displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `fields_for` creates a scope around model and not tag inside. So, as far as I know you have, you should build it from controller the appropriate models you want to loop through.

Second, since you indicated in some comment that `= builder.options[:child_index]` didn't work and that there are as many `user_partners` as `user_partnerships`, you can try this :

```
= @model.user_partnerships.each.with_index do |user_partnership,index|
    = f.fields_for :user_partnerships, user_partnership do |builder|
      %ul
        = builder.hidden_field :user_id
        = content_tag(:li, :id => "#{users[index].name})"
```

Btw, the iterator for `fields_for` seems to have been a long standing question, and it was expected that would come with rails `3.2` some method `fields_for_with_index`. I found this [post](https://github.com/jmbejar/rails/commit/7c562d5e460d97b18e4f3367b3cfb13401732920) interesting, but in my rails `3.2.13`, I didn't find any method of this kind. So perhaps, we can rely on `*.options[:child_index]` but I never tested it !

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need fields for user_partners for each instance of users.

In your controller you need

```
@instance_variable = @model.user_partnership.build
```

Then you should loop over the users and build a form for each instance.

```
= form_for @model do |f|
...
 - users.each do |index|
  = f.fields_for :user_partnership do |builder|
      = builder.hidden_field :user_partner_id
      = content_tag(:li,index.name)
```

Like others have pointed out your classes should inherit from activerecord and you to check the case and pluralization. Give the guide a read.  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html